# MongoDB .Net Linq GroupBy Child Array AsQueryable

Tags: .net, mongodb, linq, grouping

[Fiddle Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GFC7mg)

Suppose I have this .Net Class:

```
public class Bundle
{
    string Name,
    IEnumerable<string> Specs
}

public class ClientProject
{
    string ProjectId,
    decimal PriceSold,
    Bundle  Item
}
```

And in my MongoDB I would have these data:

```
[
{ProjectId: "1", PriceSold: 100, Item: {Name: "Package1", Specs: ["A", "B"]} } ,
{ProjectId: "2", PriceSold: 500, Item: {Name: "Package10", Specs: ["A", "C"]} } ,
{ProjectId: "3", PriceSold: 900, Item: {Name: "Package100", Specs: ["D", "E"]} } ,
{ProjectId: "4", PriceSold: 50, Item: {Name: "Package90", Specs: ["F"]} } ,
]
```

I want to Group by Bundle.Specs, to have this result

```
[
{Spec: "A", Total: 600},
{Spec: "B", Total: 100},
{Spec: "C", Total: 500},
{Spec: "D", Total: 900},
{Spec: "E", Total: 900},
{Spec: "F", Total: 50},
]
```

But when I run this LINQ query, it returns the wrong grouping

```
var result = _coll.AsQueryable()
   .GroupBy(xx=> xx.Item.Specs)
   .Select(xx=> new {GroupId = xx.Key, GroupSum = xx.Sum(yy=> yy.PriceSold)})
   .ToList();
```

The result:

```
[
{GroupId: ["A", "B"], GroupSum: 100},
{GroupId: ["A", "C"], GroupSum: 500},
{GroupId: ["D", "E"], GroupSum: 900},
{GroupId: ["F"], GroupSum: 50},
]
```

Whats wrong?

Here is a Fiddle of the code:

[Fiddle Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GFC7mg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to convert this:

```
{GroupId: ["A", "B"], GroupSum: 100},
{GroupId: ["A", "C"], GroupSum: 500},
{GroupId: ["D", "E"], GroupSum: 900},
{GroupId: ["F"], GroupSum: 50}
```

to this:

```
{Spec: "A", Total: 100},
{Spec: "B", Total: 100},
{Spec: "A", Total: 500},
{Spec: "C", Total: 500},
{Spec: "D", Total: 900},
{Spec: "E", Total: 900},
{Spec: "F", Total: 50}
```

for this reason you should convert Specs to an `IEnumerable<string>` as below:

```
var results = collection
    .Select(list => new { Specs = list.Item.Specs.Select(s => string.Join(",", s.Split())), Price = list.PriceSold })
    .SelectMany(i => i.Specs.Select(s => new { Spec = s, i.Price }));
```

Now your collection is ready to sum up duplicates. To do that you should add a GroupBy and a Select to your query:

```
// this is the final version
var results = collection
    .Select(list => new { Specs = list.Item.Specs.Select(s => string.Join(",", s.Split())), Price = list.PriceSold })
    .SelectMany(i => i.Specs.Select(s => new { Spec = s, i.Price }))
    .GroupBy(g => new { g.Spec, g.Price })
    .Select(i => new { i.Key.Spec, Total = i.Sum(p => p.Price) });
```

**Note**: *If it didn't worked for you (Don't worry, it didn't worked for me either. I tried with different .net versions but nothing happend.), just remove GroupBy and **last Select** and add their linq version to your project.*

Your queries should look like:

```
var results = collection
    .Select(list => new { Specs = list.Item.Specs.Select(s => string.Join(",", s.Split())), Price = list.PriceSold })
    .SelectMany(i => i.Specs.Select(s => new { Spec = s, i.Price }));

var res = from r in rawCollection
          orderby r.Spec
          group r by r.Spec into grp
          let total = grp.Where(x => x.Spec == grp.Key).Sum(x => x.Price)
          select new
          {
              Spec = grp.Key,
              Total = total
          };
```

And your desired output is waiting.